# Assign Control ID using Server Tag in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a aspx page and want to generate the page dynamically using a DataTable using server tags.

My code looks like this:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <% foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in UserReports.Rows) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <% if (row["ID"] != DBNull.Value) { %>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p><%=row["ReportTitle"]%></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnRunReport_<%=row["ID"]%>" runat="server" Text="Open" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <% } %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

When I navigate to my page I get error:

> Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs

The error happens here and I tried different comination of using the server tag but could not find out the right way of assigning the ID to the dynamically creating button.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRunReport_<%=row["ID"] %>"
```

Comment: You should look into using the Repeater control or use the attribute Command Name and Command Argument in the actual button itself.  Let me know if you need examples.

Comment: Thanks for advise. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a DataBinding expression, you need to write is like this

```
//this does not work
<asp:Button ID='<%# "btnRunReport_" + row["ID"] %>' runat="server" Text="Open" />

//this does because you cannot dynamically set the ID but every other property
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass='<%# "btnRunReport_" + row["ID"] %>' runat="server" Text="Open" />
```

But you have to call `DataBind()` manually in `Page_Load` for that to work.

But I would recommend you look into a GridView Control. It creates a `<table>` in html and you can have other Controls in the ItemTemplates

Comment: This does not work as it create this : protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button <%# "btnRunReport_" + row["ID"] %>; in designer.cs file

Comment: Ah, i was not paying attention. This does not work for `ID`, but it does for every other property. But why want you to set the ID yourself? This sound like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you need it in the front-end then there are other solutions.